# Can anybody help me with Spatial Join in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I have a doubt, I do not find what's happening. Screenshot:

Using the Join (Join data from another layer based on spatial location) I have done an Spatial Join by location, and it is said that the FIELD "Count_" must to count the number of elements (in my case Points) within it. But when I see its metadata, I find that there more "number of elements" within the polygon! So, my question: Why do I have more countered elements?

Thanks for all.

----EDIT----

Done only with a simple example of 1 polygon with some points nearby and inside, it works. 5 elements and countered 5 elements. But still don't know why counts more elements with the raw data.  :(

[image: I choose...]

[image: sample]

[image: Spatial Join]

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem, but everything goes in the right way. Could you share your original data and tell us the arcgis version? Cursore I don't have enought reputation to comment your question

Comment: I also tried to replicate the problem and mine worked ok. Did you try exporting your points to a new shapefile and trying it with that file?  I wonder if there could be some problem with your points shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.

There was a mistake with ArcGIS software, although it has a proprietary license and the original software.

Rebooting the soft cleared the mistake. Thanks for your time!